# Profile image issue

Tags: bug, profile-page, android-app

I have updated my profile image via the Stack Overflow website. Though the changes are reflected in the profile screen in the app after refreshing, in the app navigation drawer it still shows the old image. I have completely closed the app and start again then also changes are not reflected.

I understood that they are saving the user profile image in the shared preference after login, but you guys should also update user details on the profile screen.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: Moto G (4)
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (64)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the cache.

After deleting the device's *cached data*, you can able to see the updated profile image.

Cached data in the path: `Settings -> Storage -> Cached data`